# Can SSIS OData results return all records in list?

Tags: 2013, rest, odata

I have an OData source that is set to return the top 500 items of a list. I want to be able to return all records even if list exceeds 500 items. Can this be done in SSIS? If so, how would I go about returning remaining result sets?

Comment: use `$top=500` in your  OData source. for remaining items you will get `__next` OData source with response.

Comment: SSIS will take care of it if $top is specified? I won't need to look for it during the call?

Comment: SSIS will not take care of it. you have to make several requests until you get all items

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't see how to retrieve __next in SSIS.